# Finding subdirectories of depth 1 that do _not_ include a file

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I am working on an open-source project. In most, but not all, of the sub-directories of depth 1, a file called "test.c" can be found. How can I find out those directories that do not include "test.c"?

For example, I have subdirectories dir1, dir2, dir3. Dir2 and dir3 have "test.c". I have to manually check them with "ls" to determine "dir1" does not have "test.c". Probably there is a simpler way (such as a bash command) to do so?  I am under Ubuntu 16. So a bash command would be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `find` command from base directory of all the sub-directories:

```
find . -type d -exec bash -c 'for d; do [[ -f "$d"/test.c ]] || echo "$d"; done' - {} +
```

This command finds all sub directories from current directory and checks for presence of file `test.c` in each directory in the bash command. If file is not present then directory name is printed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand the "find" syntax but could you explain a bit the part after -exec?  In particular, I would like to limit the search to directories on depth 1. How would I do that with your command?

Comment: You can use `-maxdepth 1` to limit depth to 1. `[[ -f "$d"/test.c ]]` is a condition that returns success of `test.c` is present in directory `$d`. `|| echo` executes `echo` command when condition is not successful so it executes `echo` when file is not present.

Comment: One more thing: What does the "- {} + " mean?

Comment: `- {}` are arguments for `bash -c` command line. `-` goes as dummy arg for `$0` and `{}` is current directory name from `find` command which goes as remaining arguments to `bash -c` command line.